# How to Dynamic generate Open Graph protocol meta tags

Tags: magento-1.8, open-graph, meta-tags

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/> 
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
```

I've tested with the `head.phtml` file,but I don't know how to get product attributes such like `sku`, `color` and `images`.

I tested with `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')` found in 
`media.phtml` on meta tag and get a blank page,but images on product view are working fine.

That confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to can add this to one of your layout files:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="open-graph" as="open-graph" template="opengraph/product.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now you need to create the file `opengraph/product.phtml` inside you theme (`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/`) with the following content:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
<?php if ($_product) : ?>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_product->getDescription())?>"/> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_product->getName())?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')?>"/>
<?php endif;?>
```

If you need to include the `sku` or `color` in there you can get them like this:

```
$sku = $_product->getSku();
$color = $_product->getAttributeText('color');
```

Clear the cache when you are done.

Comment: is there any other way to add social meta on the fly

Comment: I offered a quick and easy way? What other way do you have in mind?